# JavaScript introspection that is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, introspection

Beginner JavaScript question.  I'm sort of spoiled on the `dir` built-in function from Python.  I want to discover the properties/methods of any object in the node.js REPL.  I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328382/how-to-do-javascript-object-introspection); the accepted answer fails (in the `node` REPL) in the simple case of an empty array `[]`.  For example:

```
for(var prop in []){console.log(prop);}  # returns undefined, prints nothing
[].length  # returns 0
```

Since the `for` loop does not discover the array's `length` method, I do not consider that to be proper introspection.  So, could someone fill in the blank here:

```
function magic(some_object) {
  # magic goes here
}

console.log(magic([]))  # should print a list that includes 'length'
```

Or is this simply not possible, or only possible for "user types"?

Comment: You can use tab completion in the REPL FYI and it works fairly well to see most things, but a complete answer to your question is fairly complicated. Mostly what you want can be achieved but it requires a fairly large bag of tricks. `util.inspect` and `console.log` in node are also handy, and I wrote my own `util.inspect` implementation at one point which I will post once I find it if an answer hasn't been accepted by then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How far back do you need to go in browser compatibility?  All of the modern browsers should support `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.  Using your example, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames([])` will return `["length"]`.

More info here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

**Edit:** Other examples:

- `Object.getOwnPropertyNames([1, 2, 3]);` returns `["0", "1", "2", "length"]`
- `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String);` returns `["prototype", "quote", "substring", "toLowerCase", "toUpperCase", "charAt", "charCodeAt", "contains", "indexOf", "lastIndexOf", "startsWith", "endsWith", "trim", "trimLeft", "trimRight", "toLocaleLowerCase", "toLocaleUpperCase", "localeCompare", "match", "search", "replace", "split", "substr", "concat", "slice", "fromCharCode", "length", "name", "arguments", "caller"]`

**Edit #2:**  Okay, so seeing that you are looking for complete list of properties and methods, including inherited ones, I've borrowed from two other SO questions (linked below) and come up with a solution that appears to get you even closer:

```
var findProperties = function(obj) {
    var aPropertiesAndMethods = [];

    do {
        aPropertiesAndMethods = aPropertiesAndMethods.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));

    for ( var a = 0; a < aPropertiesAndMethods.length; ++a) {
        for ( var b = a + 1; b < aPropertiesAndMethods.length; ++b) {
            if (aPropertiesAndMethods[a] === aPropertiesAndMethods[b]) {
                aPropertiesAndMethods.splice(a--, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return aPropertiesAndMethods;
}
```

So if you use call `findProperties([])`, it returns `["length", "join", "reverse", "sort", "push", "pop", "shift", "unshift", "splice", "concat", "slice", "lastIndexOf", "indexOf", "forEach", "map", "reduce", "reduceRight", "filter", "some", "every", "iterator", "constructor", "toSource", "toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "watch", "unwatch", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "__defineGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "__lookupSetter__"]`

**Linked Questions**

[javascript inheritance, reflection and prototype chain walking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706210/javascript-inheritance-reflection-and-prototype-chain-walking)

[How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Well, I'm in `node` not a browser, but this is in the right direction.  Still not giving me everything though.  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames([])` returns `[ 'length' ]`, though an empty array also has a `.toString()` method.  And `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array)` provides more methods (including `prototype`) but still not `toString`.  You get my upvote but I'd still like to programmatically get *all* the properties/methods that are valid if I can.

Comment: Okay, so you are not only looking for the properties and methods of the actual object, but the ones that it inherits as well?  Because, technically, `toString` is a method of `Object.prototype` and that is simply inherited by `Array`. Not sure if there is any way to grab the inherited methods and properties as well . . .

Comment: Aha I think I'm learning here.  So I could write a function that follows the inheritance tree up to `Object` and builds a set of everything it finds?  I don't see an obvious way to do that.  `Object.getPrototypeOf([])` just returns `[]` not `Array`.

Comment: Funny you should ask . . . while you were typing that, I was writing that very function.   :D   Special thanks to some of the answers in the two threads that I linked for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, and I added it to my answer, if that was not clear.   LOL

Comment: Your `findProperties` function appears to be exactly what I'm looking for.  It shows me that `[]` has `push`, `toString`, etc. and that functions have `call` and `apply` properties.  It still doesn't work for some things (`null`, `undefined`, `2`, `''`) but I assume that is because those things are not really considered to be objects and don't have properties anyway.  For example while it doesn't work for `''` it does work for `new String('')` which is considered different.

Comment: You can get a return for `2` if you make it a defined `Number` object (i.e., `console.log(findProperties(new Number(2)));`).  Interestingly, it gives you a different result than `console.log(findProperties(Number));`, showing the difference between an object (e.g., `Number`) and an instance of an object (e.g. `2`).

Comment: I upvoted this years ago. I wish I could upvote it again because I use it all the time!

Comment: @MarkMcClure - Glad it helped!  Honestly, it's probably the most interesting conversation that I've ever had on SO.   :D